# WordPress: Integrate JavaScript in Admin Pannel in edit.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am developing a plugin in WordPress and for the same plugin in settings page I want to integrate a jquery in backend on **edit.php**. I have followed the below method but it is not working

```
function cs_colorpicker_js() {
 wp_enqueue_script('cs_colorpicker_js',
                   plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/cs_colorpicker.js'
                   );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cs_colorpicker_js' );
```

here is the screenshot of one error that i have found. http://goo.gl/wmgH60

Comment: Are you using jQuery instead of $ in the script?

Comment: (http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/) i am using jquerry from here. I am having zero knowledge about jQueries.

Comment: I've checked it.. No i am using jquery only and not $.

Comment: see here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_Scripts_Only_on_a_Plugin_Administration_Screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the third variable of [Wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) like,

```
function cs_colorpicker_js() {
     wp_enqueue_script('cs_colorpicker_js',
                        plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/cs_colorpicker.js',
                        array('jquery') // jquery dependency
     );
}
```

Comment: tried adding third field but still jquerry is not working up.

Comment: Try to use the last `$in_footer` parameter, means set it to true

Comment: tried putting $in_footer as true in wp_enqueue_script still not working

Comment: check in console,are you getting any error. Also check that your colorpicker js is added or not?

Comment: debugged it with firebug but no errors or warning. It is working fine if implemented separately without wordpress in pure html. yes, it is added in wordpress and i can even create the breakpoints in it with firebug. i don't know much but do you think it could be the problem of jquery conflicting? I'm having that doubt. Thanks for all the help.